# Add default properties when inheriting reactjs class in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to add a default property that should refer to an instance function when I am inheriting a component class in ReactJS, and ES6. In detail, I have the datepicker from npm (react-day-picker) and want to make sure that two properties are always sent to the base class:

```
export default class DayPicker extends BaseDayPicker {
constructor(props) {
    var { ...newProps } = props;
    newProps.onMouseDown = this.onDayPickerMouseDown;
    newProps.onMouseUp = this.onDayPickerMouseUp;
    super(newProps);
}

componentDidMount() {
    super.componentDidMount && super.componentDidMount();
    window.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onPageClick, false);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    super.componentWillUnmount && super.componentWillUnmount();
    window.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onPageClick, false);
}   

onPageClick = (e) => {
    if (!this.isDayPickerMouseDown) {
        this.props.onPageClick && this.props.onPageClick();
    }
};  

onDayPickerMouseDown = (e) => {
    this.isDayPickerMouseDown = true;
};

onDayPickerMouseUp = (e) => {
    this.isDayPickerMouseDown = false;
};  

render() {
    return super.render();
}
```

}

The problem with the code above is that I get `'this' is not allowed before super()`.

I cannot find a way to solve this. If it is not possible to add default properties that must use `this`, is it possible to solve it in the render method?

Comment: Move `super(newProps);` to the top of the constructor function rather at the bottom?

Comment: That would exclude my new properties from the render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Referencing my comment on another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678317/add-default-properties-when-inheriting-reactjs-class-in-es6/36678520?noredirect=1#comment60952900_36678520)

You should **lean away** from *inheritance*, it is an anti-pattern.

React was designed for **composition**. *What does that mean?* If you have some functionality to share, then put it in a component and make it use props in different ways.

**TL;DR** You want to use ***Higher-Order Components*** for this type of situation.

Example:

```
BaseDayPicker = (RenderedComponent) =>  React.Component {
  // just a function that takes a component, and returns a component.
  onMouseDown() {
    this.props.onMouseDown(doSomething());
  }

  onMouseUp() {
    this.props.onMouseUp();
  }

  //...
  // notice it renders the component that came in as a parameter.
  render(){
    return (<RenderedComponent 
      onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp} 
      onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
    />)  // it also adds some props! super cool
  }
} 

class DayPicker extends React.Comnponent {
  //...

  onMouseDown() {
    this.isDayPickerMouseDown = true;
    this.props.onMouseDown();
  }

  onMouseUp() {
    this.isDayPickerMouseDown = false;
    this.props..onMouseUp();
  }

  //....
} 
// NOTICE, WRAPPING ONE IN ANOTHER
export BaseDayPicker(DayPicker)
```

If you want to know WHY, here is a blog post explaining why [react mixins are dead](https://medium.com/@blairanderson/how-to-create-react-higher-order-components-and-why-do-i-care-210a4ad48061#.shiwbcgr4).

Comment: heres a blog post explaining more thoroughly https://medium.com/@blairanderson/how-to-create-react-higher-order-components-and-why-do-i-care-210a4ad48061#.243ym7uec

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is to specify two empty functions in parent class and then you can override them in child class.

```
class BaseDayPicker extends React.Comnponent {
  //...

  onMouseDown() {
    this.props.onMouseDown();
  }

  onMouseUp() {
    this.props.onMouseUp();
  }

  //....
} 

class DayPicker extends React.Comnponent {
  //...

  onMouseDown() {
    this.isDayPickerMouseDown = true;
    super.onMouseDown();
  }

  onMouseUp() {
    this.isDayPickerMouseDown = false;
    super.onMouseUp();
  }

  //....
}
```

So in this case you can call class method and function passed within props.

In your case it would be better to wrap `BaseDayPicker` into another component that would extend it functionality instead of trying to extend component itself.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I don´t want to change the code of the base class (maybe doing a pull request to the npm module is the best solution, if I still go for that solution).

Comment: Could you show the source code of BaseDayPicker class?

Comment: It is this one: https://github.com/gpbl/react-day-picker (which I did not write). It is just called BaseDayPicker in my code because I do 
import { default as BaseDayPicker } from "react-day-picker";

Comment: You are trying to make react do things it is not made to do. 

React was designed for composition, not inheritance. Thats why they get rid of mixins.

Comment: I dont see `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp` props in source code

Comment: @DmitriyNevzorov The component passes on all properties in the render method (see https://github.com/gpbl/react-day-picker/blob/master/src/DayPicker.js#L487), so that´s how onMouseDown etc would work.

Comment: @BlairAnderson Ok, thanks. I guess I will have to rethink my solution then. Please feel free to mention this in an answer and I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: @Sten if you provide more context about what you're trying to solve we can help re-architect in react style.

Comment: @BlairAnderson Your new answer was perfect. Thanks for enlightening me about composition!